# Escaping backslashed doublequote combined with a doublequote? (ie. \"")

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysql-real-escape-string

I have the following code:

```
<?
    $string="< input type=button value='Open' onclick='document.location.href=\"".format_URL("phpfolder",$sesion)."objects/construct.php?id_object=$id_object\"' >";
    mysql_query( "insert into db (code) values ('$string')" );
?>
```

When escaping with `$string=mysql_real_escape_string($string);` the result is

```
$string=\"< input type=button value=\'Open\' onclick=\'document.location.href=\"\".format_URL(\"phpfolder\",$sesion).\"objects/construct.php?id_object=$id_object\"\' >\";
```

And it should be like this:

```
$string=\"< input type=button value=\'Open\' onclick=\'document.location.href=\\\"\".format_URL(\"phpfolder\",$sesion).\"objects/construct.php?id_object=$id_object\\\"\' >\";
```

Why mysql_real_escape_string() don't recognize that it has to escape the first backslash of `\""` to convert it to `\\\"\"` ?

Is this a bug in PHP ?

I've tried to apply the functions like addslashes, html_entities, str_replace, preg_replace, etc. Nothing works as expected or I'm using it wrong.

What's the way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand where the first backslash in `$string=\"` is coming from. That quote isn't part of the string, it's the delimiter around the PHP string.

Comment: I concur with Barmar: From the code you posted, I don't see why the `mysql_real_escape_string` function would be adding a backslash and  double quote character. Based on the first `$string="<input...` assignment, the first character in `$string` would the the less than sign. There's no reason `mysql_real_escape_string` would add the  backslash and double quote characters. There's something else (you haven't shown) going on.

Comment: My mistake, the $string comes within a textarea for a php code editor project I'm working on. That's the reason I need the escaping to work in this cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply dont use **mysql_*** functions. Just use prepared statements and you will NOT have this problem. Here is an example in PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdoObject->prepare('INSERT INTO MyTable (code) VALUES (:code)');

$stmt->bindParam(':code', $string, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
   echo 'Success';
} else {
   echo 'Failure';
}
```

As simple as that. Much cleaner & safer code.

Now the main problem is you saving entire html/js into table. Your table will grow huge very fast in terms of size. Why dont you just save essential ID's or attributes into the table & build that html by retrieving it from the table.

You should only be saving `$session` & `$id_object` into your table. With those two variables you can build the html after.

Comment: The code editor project is for the developers in our department so they don't need to access the server to upload or download code scripts. That way I can enforce safety issues and save complete code versions. No problem with the amount of DB needed as is a close enviroment.

Comment: As for the prepared statement  I'll look into it. Have any PHP example you can share or reference?

Comment: This worked as expected. I haven't work with PDO, I'll give a full try to see it's extents.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is escaping the double quote on assignment to the $string variable.

```
<?php

$string = "< input type=button value='Open' onclick='document.location.href=\"".'url_output'."objects/construct.php?id_object=id_object\"' >";

echo $string;
```

output:

```
< input type=button value='Open' onclick='document.location.href="url_outputobjects/construct.php?id_object=id_object"' >
```

So when it's given as an argument to mysql_real_escape_string, the backslash isn't there to begin with.

The double-quote is inside the string literal's double-quote delimiters, so the backslash in front of it is escaping that double-quote for the assignment operator.

Simplified example:

```
<?php

$string = "This is a \"string literal\"";

echo $string;
```

output:

```
This is a "string literal"
```